# Error when counting rows from postgresql database

Tags: c#, postgresql

I have button click:

```
{
        NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5435;User Id=postgres;" +
         "Password=postgres;Database=testdb;");
        conn.Open();
        NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `Doc`.`Headers`", conn);
        Int64 count = (Int64)command.ExecuteScalar();
        MessageBox.Show($"Counter{count}");
        conn.Close();
    }
```

but after i run the program and press the buton i have error on line:
Int64 count = (Int64)command.ExecuteScalar();

Npgsql.PostgresException: „42601: error near "`"”

It should works, sql count receives only a number.
I do not know how to fix the code, thanks for help

Comment: Maybe if you get rid of the ` characters in the select statement it will work?

Comment: If you execute that command directly against the database, outside of your app, what happens?

Comment: @JamesFaix in pgadmin i have SELECT COUNT(*)
 FROM "Doc"."Headers"; but the sign " making an error in visual studio, so I have changed it to : "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `Doc`.`Headers`"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have capitals in the table/column names, use double quotes, not back ticks. `"Doc"."Headers"`

In C#, you'd have to escape a second set of double quotes. This can be done a few ways.

```
// if using `@`
string x = @"select * from ""Doc"".""Headers"" ";

// if not using `@`
string y = "select * from \"Doc\".\"Headers\" ";
```

However, if you created the table using capitals without double quotes, Postgres should have lowered your names.

E.g.:
`create table DOCS` would create a table actually called `docs`. To create it with capitals you would need `create table "DOCS"`.

The one exception is if you use a program that does this for you. There was at least one version of pgAdmin that did this during creation. I have since learned my lesson and only use lowercase + underscores to avoid having to quote identifiers.

Comment: I would never find that solution, This one works great "select * from \"Doc\".\"Headers\" ";